# jQuery AJAX load the exact div again after successful call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I've created a small app similiar to social media where people can create "status updates" and also comment on them. I'm fetching all the "status updates" along with comments from the database with PHP and display all of them with PHP's `foreach()` loop.

My goal is that everytime user posts a comment, it will store the comment in the database without refreshing the page (OBVIOUSLY) and after that load the ul.comments again. The problem is that since I'm fetching those status updates with foreach() loop, there are several ul.comments out there and my current JS-script can't figure out which ul.comments needs to be updated.

**Here's a part of my mark-up (the comment-part only):**

```
<?php if($comments = $this->comment_model->getComments($event['event_id'])):?>
    <?php foreach($comments as $comment):?>
    <ul class="comments">
    <li>
    <a href="<?=base_url()?>user/<?=$comment['user_id']?>">
        <img class="comment-img" src="<?=base_url()?>public/images/uploads/<?=$comment['profilepic']?>" alt="prof-img"/>
    </a>

    <a href="<?=base_url()?>user/<?=$comment['user_id']?>">
        <span class="comment-name"><?=$comment['name']?></span>
    </a>

    <span class="comment-comment"><?=$comment['comment']?></span>

    <?php if($comment['user_id'] == $this->session->userdata('user_id') || $this->session->userdata('user_type') == 1):?>
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>comments/delete/<?=$comment['id']?>">Delete</a>             
    <?php endif?>

    <span class="comment-date"><?=date('d.m.Y G:i', strtotime($comment['commented_at']))?></span>
    </li>           
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif?>
```

**And here's my AJAX call for posting comments:**

```
$("form.add-comment").on('submit', function(e) {
        var from = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: from.attr('action'),
                type: from.attr('method'),
                data: $(from).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                        from.find(".comment_submit").hide();
                        from.find("#spinner_comment").show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.st == 0) {
                            for(var key in data.msg) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }

                        }
                        if(data.st == 1) {
                            $("#event_comment").val(''); 
                            $.get(window.location,function(data){
                                $data = $.parseHTML(data);       
                                $("ul.comments",from).html( $("ul.comments",$data).html());
                                });
                        }

                    }, complete: function() {
                        from.find("#spinner_comment").hide();
                        from.find(".comment_submit").show();
                    }
                });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

**And here's my CI controller/method for posting the comment**

```
public function add() {

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_comment', 'Comment', 'required|htmlspecialchars');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === false) {

                $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 0)));
                return false;

            } else {

                $data = array (
                            'event_id' => $this->input->post('event_id'),
                            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                            'comment' => $this->input->post('event_comment')
                        );

                    $add_comment = $this->comment_model->addComment($data);
            }

            if($add_comment === true) {

                $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 1)));
                return false;

            } else {

                $this->output->set_content_type('application_json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('st' => 0)));
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new ul every loop. Leave the ul alone and iterate through the li elements and give them an identifier where you can identify which post must be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because you're url isn't found/or not loading.

Instead of:

```
from.find('ul.comments').load(window.location+' ul.comments');
```

Try this:

```
$.get(window.location,function(data){
   $data = $.parseHTML(data);       
   $("ul.comments",from).html( $("ul.comments",$data).html() );
});
```

Comment: Nothing.. It will add it to the database, but I can see the new comment only if I refresh the page. In "Developers Tool" I can only view the JSON I got back from the server if I open the "Network" > "Preview" Tab

Comment: What does it say in your console, is it fetching the url after the post?

Comment: Still nothing. The AJAX part is working just fine, but I still have to refresh the page to see new comment(s). What do you mean by fetching the url after the post? I only have that (window.location) in my .load()

Comment: **What does it say in your console, is it fetching the url you have in your `.load()` after the post?**

Comment: No, the only thing I see from the "Network" tab is the method which will add that comment into database.

Comment: Now I do get the same page back again with GET but I can only view it in the "Network" tab. ICYMI, I have the markup and the JS-script in same file

Comment: Check the edit, it might be what you need. But I would be doing this with JSON, and populating the comments with JSON, so there won't be formatting issues and so you don't have to load the entire document again, despite ajax request or not.

Comment: Still the same thing.. I can see the updates only in the "Network" > "Preview" Tab but the document doesn't load the new content without refreshing the page.

Comment: I edited my OP, you can see the actual PHP action and the updated JS now.

Answer (score 0):

If your "statuses" have an ID column (or any primary/unique key) in your database, you could pull that and assign it its corresponding unordered list's ID (or put the unordered lists in a container div with that ID).

Then, when you go to update the comments with your javascript, you can call the unordered list or div element by its ID and do whatever you need to - whipe clean and rewrite all of the comments - or only append comments where necessary (and remove others that have been deleted).

Your from.find("ul.comments") should return every single unordered list of the comments class.  You want to iterate through your "statuses to update" list and find the corresponding unordered list, by id.

This example assumes an ID of "StatusUL123" for the unordered list for StatusObject of ID 123.

```
foreach (StatusObject in NewStatusObjects)
{
    $("#StatusUL" + StatusObject.ID).empty(); //clears UL

    foreach (CommentObject in StatusObject.CommentObjects){
        $("#StatusUL" + StatusObject.ID).append("<li ID='CommentLI" + CommentObject.ID + "'>" + CommentObject.Info + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have an ID column for each of my statuses, and already assigned it to it's corresponding unordered list. I'm not sure what should I do next? What should I modify? Can you give me a quick example based on the JS snippet I OP'ed.